# Need an example of how to do a button click on serenity-js

Tags: serenity-js

I am really new to serenity-js and Protractor. I followed the 'https://github.com/serenity-js/seed-cucumber/tree/master/features' to get familiar with serenity-js. Can someone give me an example of how to do a button click?

E.g click on 'TRY THE NEW ANGULAR'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great place to start is to follow [the official tutorial](https://serenity-js.org/from-scripts-to-serenity/readme.html).

To click on a button you'll need:

```js
// an Actor
const actor = Actor.named('Bob').whoCan(BrowseTheWeb.using(protractor.browser));

// a Target
const LandingPage = {
  Buy_Now = Target.the('"Buy Now" button').located(by.id('#buy-now'));
}

// to tell the actor to perform the Click
actor.attemptsTo(
  Click.on(LandingPage.Buy_Now),
);
```

Hope this helps!

Jan

Comment: Hi @janmolak, Thanks